# Problema ao instalar o Chrome do PlayWright no Heroku usando Python

Tags: python, heroku

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de WebScraping usando o PlayWright, porem ao fazer o deploy no heroku ele nao consegue fazer a instalação dos navegadores usando o comando `playwright install` cheguei a executar o comando direto no console do heroku, ele faz a instalação mas também nao deu certo.

estou utilizando o buildpack `https://github.com/mxschmitt/heroku-playwright-buildpack.git`

[Log Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLdRP.png)

no local está funcionando perfeitamente, mas quando joga no heroku da esse problema, já tentei diversas soluções mas nenhuma funcionou.

trecho do código.

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(chromium_sandbox=False)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problema solucionado com o seguinte trecho no código

```
`import subprocess
 from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

 subprocess.run(["playwright", "install", "chromium"])

 with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    # ...`
```

[Link da ajuda no Stackoverflow gringo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73071242/problem-installing-playwright-chrome-on-heroku-using-python/73071601#73071601)